# Google OAuth2 Service Accounts authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to perform Google Drive API calls using "Service Accounts" authorization.

I'm calling the API, but `files.list` returns me empty set, meanwhile the drive is not empty.
I guess I should specify `prn` field as well in order to perform call on behalf of the concrete user (I don't really get who is it called for when `prn` is not specified). The problem is that when I specify `prn` authorization returns me `access_denied` error.

```
{
  "error" : "access_denied"
}
```

Documentation says that I should enable client API access from control panel
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162106

Here is what I've done, but this doesn't help much, it still gives me `access_denied`.

[image: 'Authorized API clients' screenshot]

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right. You indeed need to authorize your app to access domain's Drive. To do this you have to associate the scopes you chose with the **service account id** that you can find in your API console. This association is made in the administrative panel of your domain, of whoch you posted a screenshot.

I think you got that, but dont forget to use the **service account email** in your Oauth2 request.

FYI, if you dont specify *prn* , you access your application's drive, which cant be accessed via the Web UI

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about application's drive. With regards to the authorization I'll check once again in one hour and respond. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any documentation about this `application's drive`?

Comment: It's just a regular Drive account without web UI. I dont know how much free space an app get though

Comment: Thanks. So I just checked my test application. In Google Api Console there is `Client ID` and `Email address` for service account client. I'm using `Email address` in `iss` field for OAuth2 request. Isn't it right?

Comment: Yeah it is the email adress for iss. Check also your doamin administrative panel. There it must me the Client ID

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Could you please rephrase? What does it mean `There it must me the Client ID` and what exactly should I look for in `Domain administrator`?

Comment: @axe The administrative panel is the screenshot you posted. In client name input, put your Service account ID (not the email). In the API scope put `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

Comment: @Jerome I'm running into a similar issue with a different scope (within the Directory API).  Is there a page that lists which scopes support access for service accounts?