# Google drive sdk, domain-wide delegation with server-application with multiple domain users

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

Using a server application with C#, how is it supposed to work when accessing users in the same domain if the authentication is only possible using:
OAuth2Authenticator interface?

I'm able to access the admin of the domain's Drive, but I'm missing the 3 legged OAuth in 2.0.

Looking at this description found at this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation
Since this is not executed as a Service, and is not using Google Apps and cannot then
access: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/mydomain
Also the IP is not known from where the machine running the server-application.

Currently I'm using: "Client ID for installed applications", and it works. But what I need is to also store files in other users in the same domain.

A other solution that works temporarily is to first store them at the admin domain account and then move them to the user domain account. But this removes the possibility to direct it to a parent/folder at the end user's drive. It will always be stored in root for that end user.

Basically what I want is following:

- A Server application is running on a local machine (admin domain account can be used)
- The application upload files to different users that are in the same domain, but with their own email address and also then have their own Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that through 2 legged oauth, which can provide domain-wide authorization.
 Here are some links for your reference:
https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/oauth#2LeggedOAuth
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2538798

Comment: 2-legged oauth is oauth 1.0, not 2.0

Comment: The link you sent is pointed to the older Google Data API that is deprecated API.

Comment: you can also use OAuth 2.0, with Service Accounts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528238/google-oauth2-service-accounts-authorization         I didn't try this before,but it should work

Comment: I at the end found out that some limited access is possible on users on the same domain, not all is possible. It needs some strange copy file, permission sets, change parentId on users folder, remove permission (admin), change owner and they where forced to be in a correct sequence in order to work and transfer a file to another as an owner (only in the same domain).

It is not possible to change owner to a user that do not belong to the same domain. So this cannot be solved fully right know.